# Linking error in static lib unless used in main project

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, ld

I'm creating a little static library for having thread pools, and it depends on 2 other homemade static libraries (a homemade `printf` and a homemade mini `libc`).

But sub-functions like `ft_bzero` are not linked in the project unless I use them on the root project, the one that needs to use thread pools library. So I have the linking error coming from my `thpool` lib.

Sample :

```
cc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -MD -I ./ -I ./jqueue -I ../libft/incs -I 
../printf/incs -o .objs/thpool_create.o -c ./thpool_create.c

ar rc libthpool.a ./.objs/thpool_create.o etcetc
```

In the libraries, I compile every `.o` and use an `ar rc libthpool.a *.o`. Then I compile `.o` from main project (a single `test.c` actually), and then

```
cc .objs/test.o -o test -L./libft -L./printf -L./thpool -lft -lftprintf -lthpool -lpthread
```

How can I solve my errors?

Comment: What errors? Which object file contains `ft_bzero`? And which library (or libraries) do you expect to contain it? Your question is [neither complete nor minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code in the `ftpool` library uses code from `ft` and `ftprintf`, you (almost certainly) need to list the libraries in the reverse order:

```
cc .objs/test.o -o test -L./libft -L./printf -L./thpool -lthpool -lftprintf  -lft -lpthread
```

When scanning a static library, the linker looks for definitions of symbols that are currently undefined.  If your test code only calls functions from `thpool`, then none of the symbols in `ft` are referenced when the `ft` library is scanned, so nothing is included from the library; if none of the symbols from `ftprintf` are referenced when the `ftprintf` library is scanned, nothing is included from `ftprintf` either.  When it comes across the symbols in `thpool` that reference things from `ft` or `ftprintf`, it's too late; the linker doesn't rescan the libraries.  Hence you need to list the libraries in an order such that all references from one library (A) to another (B) are found by linking (A) before (B).  If the test code references some of the functions in `ft` or `ftprintf`, you may get lucky, or a bit lucky; some symbols may be linked in.  But if there are functions in `thpool` that make the first reference to a function in `ft`, with the order in the question, you've lost the chance to link everything.  Hence the suggested reordering.

Another (very grubby, but nonetheless effective) technique is to rescan the static libraries by listing them several times on the command line.

With shared libraries, the rules of linking are different.  If a shared library satisfies any symbol, the whole library will be available, so the linker remembers all the defined symbols, and you might well get away with the original link order.

You might need to look up 'topological sort'.  You should certainly aim to design your static libraries so that there are no loops in the dependencies; that leads to cycles of dependencies, and the only reliable solutions are either to rescan the libraries or combine the libraries.